# How to configure Infinispan 8.0.1 in Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jboss, xml-parsing, infinispan, jboss-eap-6

I am new to Infinispan and JBOSS Cache, and am trying to learn these concepts using infinispan documentation. But was not successful in configuring custom xml configuration for cache. Can you please help me out ??

I have following Java Class (Infinispan jar files added to build path)

CustomCacheBean.java

```
package com.jboss.cache;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.eviction.EvictionStrategy;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;
public class CustomCacheBean {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  EmbeddedCacheManager manager = 
           new DefaultCacheManager();
           manager.defineConfiguration("custom-cache",new ConfigurationBuilder().build());
           Cache<Object, Object> c = manager.getCache("custom-cache");
   try {
        c = new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml").getCache("xml-configured-cache");
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

And following is my xml

infinispan.xml (placed under web_Content folder)

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.0.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.0.1.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.0.1">
    <namedCache name="xml-configured-cache">
            <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="10" />
    </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

When I try to execute CustomCacheBean java class, I am getting following error

Console :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (infinispan.org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000327: Cannot find a parser for element 'infinispan' in namespace 
'urn:infinispan:config:8.0.1'. Check that your configuration is up-to date for this version of Infinispan.
at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:147)
at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:131)
at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:118)
at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:105)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:271)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:244)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:231)
at com.jboss.cache.CustomCacheBean.main(CustomCacheBean.java:19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Java based configuration instead of XML. You may take a look at tutorials:

- [Tutorials page](http://infinispan.org/tutorials/)
- [Distributed Cache (which is probably what you will need)](http://infinispan.org/tutorials/simple/distributed/)

Please note there is a Github button at the bottom of the page (which will navigate you to the Github repository).

Comment: Yes, i could manage to do simple programmatic cache using default and custom cache. It could be very helpful if i could also learn configuring using xml files.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using wrong namespace in the XML config - namespaces don't use micro version, therefore, use:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.0.xsd" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.0"
```

instead of

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.0.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.0.1.xsd" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.0.1"
```

Please, make sure that your IDE validates your configuration against the XSD; this can save you a lot of fuss (not only with Infinispan).